# Multiselect Attribute created through module can't be set programatically

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, multiselect-attribute, multiselect

I am on a Magento 2.1 installation using a Venus Theme Module called Brands 2.0.

The module creates a product_brand multi select attribute with the following code:

```
$eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $data = array(
            'group' => 'General',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'input' => 'multiselect',
            'default' => 1,
            'label' => 'Product Brand',
            'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
            'frontend' => '',
            'source' => 'Ves\Brand\Model\Brandlist',
            'visible' => 1,
            'required' => 1,
            'user_defined' => 1,
            'used_for_price_rules' => 1,
            'position' => 2,
            'unique' => 0,
            'default' => '',
            'sort_order' => 100,
            'is_global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
            'is_required' => 0,
            'is_configurable' => 1,
            'is_searchable' => 0,
            'is_visible_in_advanced_search' => 0,
            'is_comparable' => 0,
            'is_filterable' => 0,
            'is_filterable_in_search' => 1,
            'is_used_for_promo_rules' => 1,
            'is_html_allowed_on_front' => 0,
            'is_visible_on_front' => 1,
            'used_in_product_listing' => 1,
            'used_for_sort_by' => 0,
            );
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'product_brand',
            $data);
```

Now we are trying to add products through an API, and everything is working fine except for setting this product_brand attribute. When using:

```
$product->setData('product_brand', $authCSV);
```

where $authCSV is a CSV list of option IDs. This works for other multi selects but not for product_brand. No errors are thrown but the attribute does not get saved along with the rest of them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your value must be array of ids from the `Ves\Brand\Model\Brandlist` source class. If you pass a text value (e.g. brand names) the source class does not recognize it correctly. I'll recommend you to inspect the `Ves\Brand\Model\Brandlist` and compare input value with expected values (I think the expected value would be generated ID of the brand but not the code\name).

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau Thanks for the advice. Currently the value passed is the ID/IDs of the matching multi select attribute. I am getting these IDs through some simple code. So its not a text value that is then not recognised. But I will go through Brandlist and see if I can find anything out